# Perl script cannot call another perl script when executing inside C# application

Tags: c#, perl

I have perl script which is being called in C#

```
perlStartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\c_sharp\\app\\test.pl";
```

Now test.pl needs another perl script which contains other functions.

```
require 'func.pl';
```

But C# gives an exception when the require line is executed. If I comment "require 'func.pl';" then the C# application does not complain.

test.pl runs flawlessly outside C#.

What changes should I make so that test.pl runs without errors in the C# app and also calls func.pl.

Follow up question - Do I have to take care of the paths specified in perlStartInfo.Arguments when I deploy the build in a production server.

Comment: You may get better responses (and possibly solve the problem for yourself) if you actually specify what exception you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is that I passed the path of the folder where the required file was to the main.pl file as an input argument.

In the main.pl file, I added the following line

$lib_path = File::Spec->catfile($ARGV[3]);

push @INC, $lib_path;

which solved the issue.